# Automator + Applescript - An error “Can’t make "f" into type alias.” - text replacement

Tags: applescript, screenshot, automator

So I established to replace a specific text inside a text file using variables, but the problem is when it comes to the second variable/ another text it simply shows me this message: “Can’t make "f" into type alias.”

I don’t know what’s wrong with the code… when I’m using it for the first variable it simply works, how Can I fix it?

Thay’s how the code looks like and just simply does the job with the first variable

```
“use framework "Foundation"
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions

property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString

on run {input, parameter}
    set stringToFind to (item 1 of input) as text
    set stringToReplace to (item 2 of input) as text
    set theTextFile to (item 3 of input)
    
    set theContent to read (theTextFile as alias) as text
    set newContent to my replace_text(theContent, stringToFind, stringToReplace)
    
    try
        set fileRef to (open for access theTextFile with write permission)
        set eof of fileRef to 0 # truncate file
        write newContent to fileRef
        close access fileRef
    on error
        close access fileRef
    end try
    # display dialog (item 1 of input) & return & (item 2 of input) & return & (item 3 of input)
    return
end run

on replace_text(atext, xfind, xreplace)
    return ((NSString's stringWithString:atext)'s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:xfind withString:xreplace) as text
end replace_text”
```

But when I’m trying to use it for the second time in the same automator workflow it just gives me this message…

“Can’t make "f" into type alias.”

“F” - I typed as a variable that replaces the old text…

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFAjg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBk7B.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4itH0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6iKs.png)

Comment: According to the error it seems that `input` is a plain string and `f` is the third character.

Comment: So how could I fix it? When you take a look on this automator worflow? Sorry i’m a total noob